# Why is my program running an infinite loop? Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a maze solver in python using the Breadth-first search. The algorith is supposed to replace the shortest path from S to E (start to end) with 1's. However, my program is running an infinite loop and the only while loop I have is at the end, so I think the problem is there. I can't figure out what is causing it.

```
import queue


def maze_3():
    maze3 = [
        '00000S000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        '00000  000000000                                               ',
        '00000  000000000  000000000000000000  000000000000000  00000000',
        '000000            00000000    000000                      00000',
        '   00000000  000000000000         000000000000000000     000000',
        '00000000         000000000000000000000000000000   0000   000000',
        '000000        000      000000000      000     000000       0000',
        '000000  000     000000000        00000000    000000          00',
        '00  000    0  0000000000  000  000   0000  00  00 00000     000',
        '000000    000000         000000000     000  0000          00000',
        '0000000000000000            0000000  0000000   000  00000000000',
        '000000        000  0000000    0000   00000000000000    00000000',
        '0000000000000000E                                       0000000',
    ]
    return maze3


def finished_maze(maze, solution=''):
    global starting_point
    for i, position in enumerate(maze[0]):
        if position == 'S':
            starting_point = i

    j = starting_point
    k = 0
    position = set()

    for move in solution:
        if move == 'Up':
            k -= 1
        elif move == 'Down':
            k += 1
        elif move == 'Left':
            j -= 1
        elif move == 'Right':
            j += 1

    for k, row in enumerate(maze):
        for j, column in enumerate(row):
            if (k, j) in position:
                print('1', end='')
            else:
                print(column, end='')
        print()


def is_valid(maze, moves):
    a = True
    for l, position in enumerate(maze[0]):
        if position == 'S':
            starting_point = l

    j = starting_point
    k = 0

    for move in moves:
        if move == 'Up':
            k -= 1
        elif move == 'Down':
            k += 1
        elif move == 'Left':
            j -= 1
        elif move == 'Right':
            j += 1

        if not ((j >= 0 and j < len(maze[0])) and (k >= 0 and k < len(maze[0]))):
            return not a
        elif maze[k][j] == '0':
            return not a
    return a


def find_solution(maze, moves):
    a = True
    for i, position in enumerate(maze[0]):
        if position == 'S':
            starting_point = i

    j = starting_point
    k = 0
    for move in moves:
        if move == 'Up':
            k -= 1
        elif move == 'Down':
            k += 1
        elif move == 'Left':
            j -= 1
        elif move == 'Right':
            j += 1

        if maze[k][j] == 'E':
            print(finished_maze(maze, moves))
            return a

    return not a


space = queue.Queue()
space.put('')
put = ''
maze = maze_3()

while not find_solution(maze, put):
    put = space.get()
    for i in ['Up', 'Down', 'Left', 'Right']:
        location = put + i
        if is_valid(maze, location):
            space.put(location)
```

Comment: I see no use in creating the maze_3() function. you could just use a string with the value of the maze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code doesn't do what you are expecting it to do:

```py
for move in moves:
```

It splits it so it gives you every single letter separately.

```
D
o
w
n
D
o
w
n
```

It should be like this: (add `import re` to the start of your file)

```py
for move in re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', moves):
```

It gives the following:

```
Right
Down
Down
Up
Up
Down
Down
Up
Down
Down
Down
Up
Left
Down
Down
Up
Right
```

Other than that, your program works, but really slowly because you are not checking if you already visited a node.

**Extra part on visited list**

If you define maze like so:

```py
def maze_3():
    maze3 = [
        '00000S000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        '00000  000000000                                               ',
        '00000  000000000  000000000000000000  000000000000000  00000000',
        '000000E           00000000    000000                      00000', # here we add an E
        '   00000000  000000000000         000000000000000000     000000',
        '00000000         000000000000000000000000000000   0000   000000',
        '000000        000      000000000      000     000000       0000',
        '000000  000     000000000        00000000    000000          00',
        '00  000    0  0000000000  000  000   0000  00  00 00000     000',
        '000000    000000         000000000     000  0000          00000',
        '0000000000000000            0000000  0000000   000  00000000000',
        '000000        000  0000000    0000   00000000000000    00000000',
        '0000000000000000E                                       0000000',
    ]
    return maze3
```

It gives the following solution, which is correct:

```
Down
Down
Right
Down
```

But if we print all the paths it checked, we can see this:

```
Up
Down
Left
Right
DownUp
...
```

The last line says it returns to the location it already visited. If you take a better look at BFS, you will see that it keeps a list of visited nodes. If you add it, it will speed up your code as you will not be checking nodes that you have already visited.

Comment: Alternatively you could just store tuples of moves so you don't need to use regular expressions